# Html and sql with python

Tags: python, html, mysql, sql

```
import urllib2

url = "http://www.bdfutbol.com/es/t/t2012-13.html"

request = urllib2.Request(url)
handle  = urllib2.urlopen(request)

content = handle.read()

splitted_page = content.split('<div class="divclassificacio">', 1);
splitted_page = splitted_page[1].split("</div>", 1);

print "Downloads: " + splitted_page[0]
```

So I just wrote this code to retrieve data, in html, from a soccer website using python. I am having issues writing the result into a file, and also displaying the table in python, which is what the code's for.

Also, I was wondering if anybody knew how can I transfer the table or the data into a MySql table?

Comment: what do you mean displaying table in python?

Comment: What you're doing here is more widely known by the term "scraping". Just thought you might find it useful when googling for examples and such.

Answer (score 1):

To write to a file you can use:

```
with open('downloads.txt', 'w') as output_file:
     output_file.write(splitted_page[0])
```

In order to transfer into MySQL (or any other database) you'll have to first model your data in a schema, and then interact with it via the python interface.
[This](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/) set of articles provide great help on how to interact with databases from python.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to parse a table from a website using python, and also storing it into a csv file?

Comment: Check out the following question. It will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250455/how-to-parse-html-table-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-and-write-to-csv